# Multiple join conditions with same columns and different columns PySpark

Tags: join, pyspark, conditional-statements, left-join, inner-join

Is there an easy way to do a multiple join by not repeating the same column in pyspark syntax?

For example, i wanna try something like this (code below):

`Input df1`

| ID | State | dt_run |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | FRANCE | 2022-02-11 |
| 2 | ENGLAND | 2022-02-11 |
| 3 | SWITZERLAND | 2022-02-11 |

`Input df2`

| ID | Country | capital_city |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | FRANCE | PARIS |
| 2 | ENGLAND | LONDON |

---

**> `df_output = df1.join(df2, ['ID', df1.State==df2.Country], 'left')`** **<- DESIDERED**

This does not work. Is it a syntax error or I am forced to repeat "==" condition also when the column name is the same?

**I don't want to do this:**

```
> condition = [df1.ID==df2.ID, df1.State==df2.Country]
> df_output = df1.join(df2, condition, 'left')
```

This is just an example. This last code gives an error because it creates 2 columns with the same name (ID). Can I only bring one? I would like to avoid renaming them first, i have a lot of datasets.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you used is the short form of join in cases where you want your join to happen by comparing the same columns (using exact same names) for both sides of the join. Please also note that the syntax you used is dropping the duplicated columns, which is not happening in the next suggested approach.

As I understand, the above case is not your case. In your case you should probably use the standard syntax to join with conditions.
This code should work:

```
df_output = df1.join(df2, (df1.ID == df2.ID) & (df1.State == df2.Country), 'left')
```

More info can be found [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.join.html).